# how to set up sublime text 2 as environment variable sublime

Tags: bash, sublime-text

I just installed sublime text 2 on Ubuntu 12.10 and would like to be able to run it as its own environment variable. Example `$ sublime somefile.js`  how do I add custom variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the most elegant solution but you can create a script in your ~/bin/sublime with the following commands:

```
cd
echo "/FULL-PATH-TO-YOUR-SUBLIME-FOLDER/sublime_text \$1" > ~/bin/sublime
chmod +x ~/bin/sublime
```

and then if your ~/bin/ folder is in your $PATH then you will be able to run `$ sublime somefile.js`

To check your $PATH just run `echo $PATH`

If you bin is not ther edit your .bashrc file and edit or add a line like the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the term [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), it seems like you want to place the a command to start Sublime Text in your path.

From the [Sublime Text installation page](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#linux):

`sudo ln -s /path/to/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl`

Note that you must use the full path or this will not work. Suggested place to extract the downloaded file to is `/opt`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the BEST way, I think!

go to your terminal and type:

sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime

(if your sublime text folder is in /opt/Sublime Text 2)

this command creates a symbolic link in /usr/bin and then you can call sublime command easily in terminal:

sublime .... (some code). That's all! :)